# What's the better way to handle event handler function with parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am try to implement event handler function to avoid a new function creation every time the component `renders` and `re-renders`.

**Scenario1:**

If I bind the function in constructor like below and without parameters in `onChange` it will create a new function in bundle file only once

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
       value: ""
    }
 } 

 handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
       value: e.target.value
    });
 }

 render(){
    const { value } = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={value} />
      </div>
    )
 }
```

**Scenario2:**

But when I want to pass `some parameters` along with `event` to `handleChange` function like below I believe it will create a new function every time the component `renders` and `re-renders`

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
       value: ""
    }
 } 

 handleChange(e, param1, param2){
    this.setState({
       value: e.target.value
    });
 }

 render(){
    const { value } = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, param1, param2)} value={value} />
      </div>
    )
 }
```

So,

> how can I write scenario 2 better so that a new function will be created
>   only once in bundle file but not every time the component renders and re-renders? Is it possible?

**Edit:**

param1 and param2 are my own custom values.

Comment: @OriDrori If I want to pass data value as props I can pass without arrow function but I want to pass event as well along with the params also when we use some external libraries they give id, name which we can't get with event.target.name or id but that needs to be passed like (e, id, name) => this.handleChange(e, id, name) so these cases it will create a new function every time so how to handle such cases is my question

Comment: I've added an answer that demonstrate your case. As you can see, there's no need for the arrow function.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - I've reopened the question because the duplicate you've referred to, doesn't actually address the OPs case.

Answer (score 1):

If the target component can pass multiple parameters (`input` obviously doesn't), your second scenario works without the need of an arrow function:

```
 render(){
    const { value } = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        <CustomInput type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={value} />
      </div>
    )
 }
```

Example:

```js
class CustomInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.inputHandleChange = this.inputHandleChange.bind(this);
  }
  
  inputHandleChange(e) {
    this.props.onChange(e, e.target.value.length, 'param2');
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <input {...this.props} onChange={this.inputHandleChange} />
    );
  }
}

class InputWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    }
  }

  handleChange(e, param1, param2) {
    console.log(e.target.value, param1, param2);
    
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      value
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <CustomInput type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={value} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <InputWrapper />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id="demo"></div>
```